# Conceptual question about dress

Tags: vocabulary

What image does one get if they read the phrase 'unveiled person'?

---

A human without dress?

---

Or a human without necessary parts of dress?

Comment: "Necessary parts of dress" is cultural bias that assumes the veil is *required*.  Veils are not a sartorial norm for most of the world.

Answer (score 4):

**Context is key**

---

[Unveil](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unveiled) has two meanings that apply here:

> 1. not hidden by a veil or other covering; bare.
> 2. revealed to public knowledge or scrutiny; made evident or manifest:

With (2) originating from the idea of covering something important up with a veil (large sheet of material), and then at some point uncovering it publicly.

The opening reveal of a new public statue for example, may be an example of something that still maintains both meanings. It is covered by a sheet to hide it from the public, until a ceremony where somebody important removes the sheet (unveils it), to announce the statue publicly. Here, it is unveiled physically (1) and metaphorically (2).

When talking about a person being "unveiled", this could therefore be either that they are physically not covered (1) or metaphorically that they have been revealed as a spectacle.

---

For example:

> The curtains opened to the play, and unveiled an old man sulking over an empty plant pot.

Here, there is no implication the person is not properly dressed. It is talking about the public reveal of one of the actors - who couldn't be seen until the curtains opened.

---

While:

> At her wedding, she chose to walk down the aisle unveiled.

Would refer to a bride at a wedding; assumed to be fully clothed, except for her [bridal veil (1.b)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veil).

---

And further:

> The wind blew cold air across the exposed regions of the man, standing unveiled to the world in proud protest.

Would imply (mainly from the context) that the man was entirely revealed to the world - wearing no clothing at all.

---

For phrases like this, the context really means everything. In general, "unveiled" is most commonly used to mean "revealed", unless in a specific religious or societal context where a "veil" means the specific headdress.

Whether "revealed" is meaning physically revealed, or metaphorically - is something you have to glean from the context of the sentence you find it in.